# Disable LiveReload with Yeoman

Tags: yeoman, livereload

When testing in IE8, LiveReload throws errors since web sockets is not supported.  Is there a way to configure yeoman to disable LiveReload?

Answer (score 4):

IE8 isn't supported by Yeoman, for good reason.

However, you could do what Allan describes, or you could override the `server` task, by putting this in your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', 'yeoman-server');
```

Comment: Basically you are right, IE8 should be sent straight to hell, but sometimes it's just the only browser that's used in a company's intranet. However, when I do that it says *Task "yeoman-server" not found.*

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `<!--[if !IE]><!--></body><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]></body><!--<![endif]-->` instead of `</body>`.

Generator would try to replace first `</body>` element and add livereload snippet before it, so code would be placed in invisible for IE space.

P.S. It`s dirty hack so use this carefuly

Comment: I hate this answer.  Also, after 90 mins, this is the best answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.registerHelper('reload:inject', function () {
  return function inject(req, res, next) {
      return next();
  }});
```

Comment: grunt.registerHelper was deprecated and now no longer exists.

Comment: In 2014 it will give you an error when you run `grunt serve`: `Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'registerHelper'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one I know.

1. Go to your project folder and find the file `Gruntfile.js`
2. Open the file in a editor
3. Remove the `reload:` in `watch:`

It will look something like this:

```
// default watch configuration
watch: {
  coffee: {
    files: 'app/scripts/**/*.coffee',
    tasks: 'coffee reload'
  },
  compass: {
    files: [
      'app/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'
    ],
    tasks: 'compass reload'
  },
  reload: {
    files: [
      'app/*.html',
      'app/styles/**/*.css',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'app/images/**/*'
    ],
    tasks: 'reload'
  }
}
```

And after you have removed it something like this:

```
// default watch configuration
watch: {
  coffee: {
    files: 'app/scripts/**/*.coffee',
    tasks: 'coffee reload'
  },
  compass: {
    files: [
      'app/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'
    ],
    tasks: 'compass reload'
  }
}
```

I think i have seen a commandline flag, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: This did not work for me, it's still put at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman Livereload consists of two parts: the middleware that inserts the livereload snippet, and the livereload target in the watch task. To disable livereload, remove both:

**Livereload snippet at the top of the Gruntfile:**

```
// Generated on ...
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729; // <- Delete this
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT}); // <- Delete this
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};
```

**Livereload task in Watch:**

```
watch: {
  // Delete this target 
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
    },
    files: [
       //...
    ]
  }
}
```

**And the middleware that inserts the snippet:**

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: 'localhost'
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          lrSnippet, // <- Delete this middleware
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
```

For updates on fixing the livereload-connect issues in Yeoman, track this issue: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/63