# how to solve the continuos reload of browser for grunt?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

When I run grunt command,the browser continuously reloads,so I am unable to debug the code,it everytime refreshes without any changes,Please any one help me in this.

Please refer the below screen of issue

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind disabling live reload, at least for debugging, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26759696/1423874